# Without using My sites is it possible to display the profile picture in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, mysites, my-profile

How to show the current user profile picture without using my sites in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? It seems to be unclear.

Comment: I need to show the Current user Profile picture in SharePoint 2013 without using My sites @AsadRefai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but there 2 things you have to make sure

1. User profile sync is enabled, photo property properly mapped n imported.
2. You also need a Mysite host location, this is required because profile picture stored in the

   User Photos/Profile Pictures
   If you don't have the Mysite host then thumbnail will not create.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,It is Possible.But you have configure User Profile Service Application in Central Admin.Please refer following link.

- [Create User Control to display User Profile Picture in SharePoint 2013 Site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1116328/Create-User-Control-to-display-User-Profile-Pictur)